# How to import functions from different files in robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am writing automation test scripts using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application ( **in .txt format** ).

Is there any option in robot framework to import functions / modules written in another files ?

**For example** :

I have written almost 300 test cases for testing our web application. All test cases contains a common function for login validation .

In case if I have to make a small change in this particular ( logIn ) function, I have go through each test case & make necessary changes .

It's really a time consuming process .

So, I just want to know , Is there any option in robot framework to write test cases in a modular way ?

Just like , if I write a ' login.txt ' function for login validation - Is there any option available in robot framework to import this particular function to any other test cases ?

Is there any keyword like 'Import Function' / 'Import Module' available for this particular scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place shared keywords in [resource files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files) and [libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-test-libraries). Resource files are almost exactly like test case files, only they don't have test cases. Libraries contain keywords written in python.

For example, you can have a file named login.txt with the keyword "Log In To My App", like this:

```
# login.txt
*** Keywords ***
Log In To My App
    <your code to log in to the app>
```

You would then include this in your other test cases like this:

```
# test_suite_1.txt
*** Settings ***
Resource     login.txt
Suite setup  log in to my app
```

```
# test_suite_2.txt
*** Settings ***
Resource     login.txt
Suite setup  log in to my app
```

Comment: Thanks @Bryan !   If I want to add more resource files in this code , can I include all those files by adding a `,`  between them ?  I got an error while attempt to do some thing like this  - `Resource   login.txt , invalidLogin.txt ` !      ( It starts working after adding both files as a separate Resource files -  `Resource  login.txt    /n Resource  dashboard.txt`  ! )

Comment: @ArunRamachandran: no, you cannot use a comma. Each resource must be imported on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Syntax

```
 *** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    my.package.TestLibrary
Library    MyLibrary    arg1    arg2
Library    PythonLibrary.py
Library    /absolute/path/JavaLibrary.java
Library    relative/path/PythonDirLib/    possible    arguments
Library    ${RESOURCES}/Example.class
```

Unlike most of the other data, the library name is both case- and space-sensitive.
If a library is in a package, the full name including the package name must be used.

Also as you asked we can import libraries from test cases also by keyword
"Import Library".
Eg:

```
*** Test Case ***
My Testcase
     Open Browser   https://facebook.com
    Import Library     My Library
    My Library.Login     ##Keyword from My Library
```